# use operator< into template

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class template with paramter T, it is a custom container. T will could be a pointer or a reference.
Into this template i have a function with which i put my objects into the container. I want to put new elements in order with operator< but the problem is that i dont know if T is a pointer or a reference. if T is a pointer i have to dereference it, otherwise not.

I find std::is_pointer::value but i have a compiletime error when i try to create a container with int T-type.

```cpp
void insert(int row, T t){
 int i = 0;    
 for (; i < size && *t < *matrix[i]; i++) { //or t < matrix[i] if T is a reference
   new_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
}
```

Comment: I think this would be a fair use for `if constexpr` to have compile time conditional code for when T is a pointer type and for when T is a reference type.

Maybe you can post the relevant code in which you use `std::is_pointer` and the corresponding compilation error.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is fantastic but.. I have to use c++11, if constexpr is a c++17 feature. There is a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You might create additional methods to unify `insert` implementation, something like:

```
template <typename T> T& deref_ptr(T* p) { return *p; }
template <typename T> T& deref_ptr(T& p) { return p; }
```

and then replace your `*t` (of pointer version) by (generic) `deref_ptr(t)` (and `*matrix[i]` by `deref_ptr(matrix[i])`):

```
void insert(int row, T t){
    for (int i = 0; i < size && deref_ptr(t) < deref_ptr(matrix[i]); i++) {
        new_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't *matrix[I]. I don't know if it is a pointer or a reference

Comment: Didn't see that also apply to `matrix[i]`. Just extend solution to also handle `matrix[i]`. Fixed.

Comment: @Jarod42 you may want to put a note at end of the answer, specifying the edit. It is a very small change, easy to miss at a glance.

Comment: @G_S: Reworded to make it more explicit.

Comment: excuse me but, in the first deref_prt, if T is, for example, A*, p is A** if I do * p, i get A* another time. Is this reasoning incorrect?

Comment: With `A a; A* p = &a;`, `deref_ptr(a)` and `deref_ptr(p)` are both equivalent to `a` (and also to `*p`).

Comment: I try it and I also print out the return value. It doesn't work because `T` is never a `T*`. It calls always the second version of `deref_ptr()`.

Comment: Work as expected here: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed499e7e0fd092bc).

Comment: oh ok but I need to use deref_ptr() into the template. in your ex you pass an `int` to the function. I need to pass a `T` value to function.
The `if constexpr` function is perfect but i have to use g++ 5.x and  if constexpr is c++17 feature and it needs a newer version of compiler.

Comment: [another demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdb0a72372965c4d). Provide problematic code if you want further help.